# C++ : constructor initialization list for an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a basic question.
I have a class with a data member : `double _mydata[N]`. (N is a template parameter).
What is the syntax to initialize these data to zero with a constructor initialization list ?
Is `_mydata({0})` OK according to the C++ standard  (and so for all compilers) ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, I think you could answer half of your question on your own rather easily since `_mydata({0})` wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, prior to C++11 you need to do just this to default-initialise each element of the array:

```
: _mydata()
```

The way you have it written won't work.

With C++11 it is more recommended use uniform initialisation syntax:

```
: _mydata { }
```

And that way you can actually put things into the array which you couldn't before:

```
: _mydata { 1, 2, 3 }
```