# initialise const array inside class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In Visual C++, how can I initialise a constant array inside of a class?

This is an example of how to do it outside of a class:

```
const char k_colors[] = 
{ 
    'R', 
    'G', 
    'B',
};
```

Now how do I need to change that? (I tried putting static in front of it, which didn't work)

Edit: You're right, I should just use single characters.

Comment: Don't you mean `const char*` and `"Red"`, etc?

Comment: Well that won't work at all, as you are using multiple character literals where it should be only a single character. Do you mean `char *` and e.g. `"Red"`?

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11 features?

Comment: If it is the same array in each object, you can make it `static` and initialize it separately.

Comment: `char` should be `char*`

Answer (score 3):

> I tried putting static in front of it, which didn't work

You can't initialise the `static` member array (or any member array) inside the class definition. Do it outside of the class definition:

```
class X
{
    static const char* k_colors[3];
};

const char* X::k_colors[] = { "Red", "Green", "Blue" };
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to be static, you'll need to initialize it outside the class:

```
class foo
{
public:
    static const char k_colors[3];
    foo() { }

};

const char foo::k_colors[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

Also, you probably want it to be a `const char *[]` since it looks like you're trying to initialize strings, so it'd be:

```
const char *foo::k_colors[] = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
```

Answer (score 1):

In  C++11 you can use the constructor initializer list as mentioned

```
class A {
    const int arr[2];

    // constructor
    A() 
    : arr ({1, 2}) 
    { }
};
```

Or you can use static const array

In header file:

```
class A {
    static const int a[2];
    // other bits follow
};
```

In source file (or in separate place from the declaration above)

```
const int A::a[] = { 1, 2 };
```

Of course you can always use `std::vector<int>` and `for` loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can initialize through the `constructor initializer` list

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694447/c-constructor-initialization-list-for-an-array)

Also the `char` should be `char*`

**Extract from the above link:**

prior to C++11 you need to do just this to default-initialise each element of the array:

```
: k_colors()
```

With C++11 it is more recommended use uniform initialisation syntax:

```
: k_colors{ }
```

And that way you can actually put things into the array which you couldn't before:

```
: k_colors{"red","green"}
```

Comment: An array?  (I think you can in C++11, but you certainly can't in C++03.)