# return array reference from function

Tags: c++

I have an image with `int[Components]` components per pixel.

I want `get()` return an `int[Components]` reference when `Components != 1` and an `int&` when `Components == 1`.

`pos` is a pointer to raw image data.

I already read this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439284) before ask, but I have no success.

The following code compiles ok, but returns garbage.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename ComponentType, uint8_t Size>
struct A
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<Size == 1,
            ComponentType&, ComponentType(&)[Size]>::type SampleType;

    SampleType get()
    {
        if constexpr (Size == 1) return *pos;
        else return reinterpret_cast<SampleType>(pos);
    }
    void advance() { pos += Size; }

    ComponentType *pos;
};  

int main()
{
    int i[10] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    A<int, 2> a{i};

    std::cout << (size_t) &a << "\r\n";
    std::cout << (size_t) a.get() << "\r\n";
    std::cout << (size_t) a.pos << "\r\n";
    std::cout << (size_t) i << "\r\n";

    for(int c : a.get())
        std::cout << c << " ";
    a.get()[1] = 1000;
    return 0;
}
```

The code has the following output. Pointer values indicates that I totally screwed.

```
2293256
2293256
2293264
2293264
2293264 0
```

Can I ask what I was terribly wrong? How to fix this? Of-course `get()` can return a pointer if `Components != 1` but I want the ability to use `for( _ : _ )`

Comment: I’m not nearly… something… enough to say that it’s safe, but I think `return *reinterpret_cast<SampleType*>(pos)` with `SampleType& get()` and `SampleType` not being a reference is closer?

Comment: (clang says dereferencing a pointer to `int[2]` `reinterpret_cast` from a pointer to `int` is still undefined behaviour, and I believe it.)

Answer (score 1):

[A `span`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one) is probably good for this.

```
template<typename ComponentType, uint8_t Size>
struct A
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<Size == 1,
            ComponentType&, span<ComponentType, Size>>::type SampleType;

    SampleType get()
    {
        if constexpr (Size == 1) return *pos;
        else return span<ComponentType, Size>(pos, Size);
    }
    void advance() { pos += Size; }

    ComponentType *pos;
};
```

Comment: I missed `span`. It is a very nice solution. But mingw64 gcc 8.1 does not support it yet.

Comment: @Chameleon: There’s a single-header implementation at https://github.com/tcbrindle/span.

Answer (score 0):

Solution strictly on returning an array reference.
Although `span` solution is very neat.

```
template<typename ComponentType, uint8_t Size>
struct A
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<Size == 1,
            ComponentType, ComponentType[Size]>::type SampleType;

    SampleType& get()
    {
        if constexpr (Size == 1) return *pos;
        else return *reinterpret_cast<SampleType*>(pos);
    }
    void advance() { pos += Size; }

    ComponentType *pos;
};
```